# Type error using useNewUrlParser with mongoose in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mongoose, webstorm, tslint

I'm doing the following:

```
// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }).then(
  () => { /** ready to use. The `mongoose.connect()` promise resolves to undefined. */ },
).catch((err: Error) => {
  console.log('MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running. ' + err)
  process.exit();
})
```

and I'm getting the following error from WebStorm TypeScript service (running TSLint manually works fine):

> TS2345: Argument of type '{ useNewUrlParser: boolean; useCreateIndex:
> boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: MongoError)
> => void'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'useNewUrlParser' does not exist in type '(err: MongoError) => void'.

This seems to be an issue with `@types/mongoose`, but I've looked everywhere and I can't find where it's coming from.

Here is a workaround which does not really explain the issue:

```
    mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true)
    mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true)
    mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI).then(...
```

**Edit:** mongoose 6 no longer need these options.

Comment: forgot to post an update: this must have been fixed in `@types/mongoose`, because I stopped seing this issue after upgrading it 1 or 2 weeks later

Answer (score 7):

These options are no longer necessary; hence why they aren't even in the type definitions. See the docs here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options

```
// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI).then(
  () => { /** ready to use. The `mongoose.connect()` promise resolves to undefined. */ },
).catch((err: Error) => {
  console.log('MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running. ' + err)
  process.exit();
})
```

Comment: The question was valid on mongoose < 6. Also, `@types/mongoose` is no longer used as mongoose now includes typings natively

Answer (score 0):

You need to have dev dependency installed

```
npm install -D @types/mongoose --save
```

Comment: I did say that it seemed to be an issue with `@types/mongoose`, meaning that it was obviously installed...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Mongoose library can throw errors even with type definitions are installed:

```
yarn add @types/mongoose  or  npm i --save-dev @types/mongoose
```

One of the remedy is to add the option `skipLibCheck: true` in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```